# javascript if/else, but still editable

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I'm creating a form that requires a field to equal another if a checkbox is checked, but still editable if the user decides to change the amount.

```
document.addEventListener("change", myFunction2);
     function myFunction2(){
          if (document.getElementById('itemize').checked==true) { 
              document.getElementById('six').value = document.getElementById('jobs_9').value;
    }
```

Right now as long as that itemize box is checked, that input box cannot be edited.  Is there a way to have the input equal, but also leave it open for revision?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the behavior is currently, and what you want the behavior to be instead.

Comment: Simply don't always copy from `#jobs_9` to `#six`, but from the changed one to the other.

Comment: currently, you can put whatever amount in "six", but when the itemize box is checked, "six" adopts whatever number is in "jobs_9".  this is all working great, but I want the ability for a user to be able to edit "six" if they don't like the amount adopted by jobs_9.  sorry, the requirements are quite confusing.

Comment: Looks like you'd profit alot from data binding. Check out Knockout.js.

Comment: hey @Bergi, can you explain that a bit more?  thanks!

Comment: When `#six` changes, put that value into `#jobs_9`. When `#jobs_9` changes, put that value into `#six`. Try using separate event listeners on every element, or check which one was the event target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to think it more in a human version.

You're saying: When the document changes, if the checkbox is checked the fields will be equal.

Try to add a listener to the checkbox!

Tell me if you could do it!

Edit: An example of what you can do (with your code):

```
var checkboxy = document.getElementById('itemize');

checkboxy.addEventListener("change", myFunction2);
     function myFunction2(){
          if (document.getElementById('itemize').checked==true) { 
              document.getElementById('six').value = document.getElementById('jobs_9').value;
    }
 }
```

Working: https://jsfiddle.net/pb2740yy/

Comment: There already is a listener that runs when the checkbox is clicked.

Comment: The listener is on the document, he only want to equal the values when the user checks it, so it can be changed then.

Comment: He already *does* only equalize the values while `#itemize` is checked?

Comment: He needs this: "Is there a way to have the input equal, but also leave it open for revision?"

Try the fiddle and remove the added js, that is his version, try to change the values after check.

Comment: OK, maybe the question is just sufficiently unclear. See @cdhowie's answer for how I understood it

Comment: Yes it is a bit unclear, i am not really sure what he needs though :P

Comment: If you aren't clear on what OP needs, the correct way to approach that is to ask for clarification in a comment, not provide an answer based on a total guess.

Answer (score 1):

Attach different handlers directly to each input, where each handler copies the value of the changed input to the other input.  Without using jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
(function () {
    var itemize = document.getElementById('itemize');

    function addChangeListener(from, to) {
        from = document.getElementById(from);
        to = document.getElementById(to);

        from.addEventListener('change', function () {
            if (itemize.checked) {
                to.value = from.value;
            }
        }
    }

    addChangeListener('six', 'jobs_9');
    addChangeListener('jobs_9', 'six');
})();
```

You will also need a handler when the `#itemize` checkbox is checked.  If the values are different in that case, you just have to pick one (unless you want to keep track of which was changed last).